# ReactJS CoffeScript Rails 4 this.setState is not a function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, reactjs

I.m new in ReactJS, so often get problems...

so:

```
@CommentBox = React.createClass
  getInitialState: ->
    data: []

  componentWillMount: ->
    request_data = null
    val = $.ajax
      url: @props.url
      dataType: 'json'
      success: (data, status, xhr) ->
        request_data = JSON.parse xhr.responseText
        @setState data: request_data
    render: ->
      .......
```

and get error in console:

```
TypeError: this.setState is not a function
  return this.setState({..
```

semple of my repo:
https://github.com/olegsobchuk/example_app

Please help me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to use `=>` instead of `->` for the success callback, so that the `this` refers to your component:

```
success: (data, status, xhr) =>
```